# Comparing two arrays of objects, keep items from array2 in order of array1

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have 2 arrays of objects:

```
const headers1 = [
    {text: 'ID', value: 'id', active: true},
    {text: 'Name', value: 'name', active: true},
    {text: 'Age', value: 'age', active: false},
    {text: 'Address', value: 'address', active: true},
    {text: 'Phone', value: 'phone', active: true}, //should be excluded because are not on headers2
]
```

and

```
const headers2 = [
    {text: 'Name',value:'name', active: true},
    {text: 'Age',value:'age', active: true}, 
    {text: 'Address',value:'address', active: true},
    {text: 'ID',value: 'id', active: true},               
    {text: 'Config',value: 'config', active: false}, //should be included at the end
    {text: 'Options',value: 'options',active: true} //sould be included at the end
]
```

So basically I need to get all items from `headers2` in order of `headers1`. Items from `headers2` which are not on `headers1` should be placed at the end. The result should be this:

```
const headers3 = [
    {text: 'ID', value: 'id', active: true},
    {text: 'Name', value: 'name', active: true},
    {text: 'Age', value: 'age', active: false},
    {text: 'Address', value: 'address', active: true},
    {text: 'Config', value: 'config', active: false},
    {text: 'Options', value: 'options', active: true}
]
```

Comment: Your result has the object for `text: 'Age'` from `headers1` (`active: false`). Is that on purpose?

Comment: Do you have some code that you've started on for this? There's probably a number of ways to do this.

Comment: @HereticMonkey yes the age should be false.

Comment: @mlibby I've just made a function to detect the different items from each array like `headers2.filter(h2 => !headers1.some(h1 => h1.value === h2.value))`

Answer (score 1):

Just sort by the index of the matching item in the other one, and if it's `-1` set the index to `Infinity`:

```js
const headers1 = [
    {text: 'ID', value: 'id', active: true},
    {text: 'Name', value: 'name', active: true},
    {text: 'Age', value: 'age', active: false},
    {text: 'Address', value: 'address', active: true},
    {text: 'Phone', value: 'phone', active: true} //should be excluded because are not on headers2
]

const headers2 = [
    {text: 'Name', value: 'name', active: true},
    {text: 'Age', value: 'age', active: true}, 
    {text: 'Address', value: 'address', active: true},
    {text: 'ID', value: 'id', active: true},               
    {text: 'Config', value: 'config', active: false}, //should be included at the end
    {text: 'Options', value: 'options', active: true} //sould be included at the end
]

const headers3 = [...headers2].sort((a, b) => {
    const aIndex = headers1.findIndex((i) => i.text === a.text) + 1 || Infinity;
    const bIndex = headers1.findIndex((i) => i.text === b.text) + 1 || Infinity;
    return aIndex - bIndex;
}).map((i) => {
    i.active = (headers1.find((el) => el.text === i.text) || i).active
    return i;
});

console.log(headers3);
```

Comment: It makes the right order but the `active` property will always be the same as `headers2` and it should get the `active` value from `headers1`

Comment: see edit i fixed it

Answer (score 1):

You could build an object with the wanted order and get a copy from the second array and sort it.

```js
const headers1 = [{ text: 'ID', value: 'id', active: true }, { text: 'Name', value: 'name', active: true }, { text: 'Age', value: 'age', active: false }, { text: 'Address', value: 'address', active: true }, { text: 'Phone', value: 'phone', active: true }],
    headers2 = [{ text: 'Name', value: 'name', active: true }, { text: 'Age', value: 'age', active: true }, { text: 'Address', value: 'address', active: true }, { text: 'ID', value: 'id', active: true }, { text: 'Config', value: 'config', active: false }, { text: 'Options', value: 'options', active: true }],
    references = headers1.reduce((r, o, i) => (r[o.text] = { o, order: i + 1 }, r), {}),
    result = headers2
        .map(o => references[o.text]?.o || o)
        .sort(({ text: a }, { text: b }) => (references[a]?.order || Number.MAX_VALUE) - (references[b]?.order || Number.MAX_VALUE));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: The order works fine but the `active` property should have the value from `headers1`. In my example the `age` should be `false`

Comment: @Fantasmic, please see edit.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `Map` on the items in `headers2`, keyed by `name`. Then collect the items from `headers1` that are in that map, and finally add to that result the items in the map that didn't match. You can use the `delete` method of the map, as that also returns whether the key was found.

This has linear time complexity in terms of the number of items in both arrays.

Here is how that works:

```js
const headers1 = [{text: 'ID', value: 'id', active: true},{text: 'Name', value: 'name', active: true},{text: 'Age', value: 'age', active: false},{text: 'Address', value: 'address', active: true},{text: 'Phone', value: 'phone', active: true}]
const headers2 = [{text: 'Name',value:'name', active: true},{text: 'Age',value:'age', active: true}, {text: 'Address',value:'address', active: true},{text: 'ID',value: 'id', active: true},{text: 'Config',value: 'config', active: false},{text: 'Options',value: 'options',active: true}];

// Collect headers2 items in a map keyed by name
const map = new Map(headers2.map(o => [o.value, o]));
// First get the items from headers1 that are in the map, delete them from that map,
// and then add the remaining map values
let headers3 = [...headers1.filter(o => map.delete(o.value)), ...map.values()];

// output result
headers3.forEach(o => console.log(JSON.stringify(o)));
```